# Some help understanding "block/scope" variables "dangers"

Tags: javascript, function

So, I have a function, and I'd like it to return multiple variables. To do that however, it seems like I need to run the function twice. E.g.

```
console.log( textCleanup(text,true,true,true,true,true,true)[0] )
console.log( textCleanup(text,true,true,true,true,true,true)[1] )
```

Now, I figured, I can just define the variables beyond the function, and have the function change them, then I don't need to run it twice. But, is it safe? I haven't been programming for very long and I feel like I night be missing information about how it all works, and to me it feels like maybe this isn't how this should be done. Would appreciate any info on this. I tried googling it, but I suppose I wasn't googling for the right terms, as I haven't found much about it.

Comment: "*To do that however, it seems like I need to run the function twice*" or, you know, once and just get the result: `const result = textCleanup(text,true,true,true,true,true,true)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're confusing the terminology here.  The function doesn't return a *variable*.  It returns a *value*.  (In this case that value appears to be a reference to an array.)  You can use a variable to *store* that value to reference it at a later time:

```
const myVar = textCleanup(text,true,true,true,true,true,true);
console.log( myVar[0] );
console.log( myVar[1] );
```

Comment: Ah, yes, I see - but wouldn't that cause the function to run twice? Once to access the first value, and then to access the second one? Thank you for the reply.

Comment: @AlonPerel: *"but wouldn't that cause the function to run twice?"* - Why?  The code here invokes the function once and stores the result of that function.  Your original code in the question above invokes the function twice.

Comment: @AlonPerel calling a function is what calls the function. Reading value from a variable does not call a function.

Comment: @David AH! Excellent - it makes sense. I checked the amount of runs with the console.logs - but ofcourse, there are two of ém and so, it runs twice, right. Thank you and VLAZ for explaining this to me :).

Answer (score 0):

You should store the resulting array from the function call.

If the parameters of the call are the same, just keep a single copy.

```js
const textCleanup = (text, a, b, c, d, e, f) => {
  return text.split(' ');
}

const doStuff = (text) => {
  // Store the result array
  const result = textCleanup(text, true, true, true, true, true, true);
  console.log(result[0]); // Access element at index 0
  console.log(result[1]); // Access element at index 1
};

doStuff('foo bar');
```

Alternatively, you can destructure or unpack the array using the following syntax.

```js
const [foo, bar] = textCleanup(text, true, true, true, true, true, true);
console.log(foo); // Access element at index 0
console.log(bar); // Access element at index 1
```